# Do i need to call create tables every time in peewee?

Tags: python, sqlite, peewee

I working in a project in which i have different projects with the same database architecture, 
so i used peewee Model in which:

```
dynamic_db = SqliteDatabase(None)
class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = dynamic_db
class KV (BaseModel):
    key = TextField()
    value = IntegerField()
```

And whenever i new project is created i will call a function

```
dynamic_db.init(r'{}\database.db'.format(ProjectName.upper()))
dynamic_db.connect()
dynamic_db.create_tables([KV])
dynamic_db.close()
```

The problem is that once this database is created, i can't access with peewee.
When i try to create a record:
`KV.create(key = 'Saul', value = 123)`
I get this error:
`peewee.InterfaceError: Error, database must be initialized before opening a connection.`

I would appreciate any help or cookbook for peewee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe something is incorrect, either in your question description, or in the error you are receiving. The call you are making to `.init()` *is* what initializes the database. After that, you should have no problems using it.

Full example which works fine:

```
from peewee import *

db = SqliteDatabase(None)

class Base(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = db

class KV(Base):
    key = TextField()
    value = IntegerField()

db.init('foo.db')  # database is now initialized
db.connect()
db.create_tables([KV])  # no problems.
db.close()
```

Comment: Thanks, but actually when i create it for the first time i have no issues.
The problem is when i run other function to create a record.
For example if i run:
KV.create(key = 'Saul', value= 123)
then i get a message saying that i should initialize the db

Comment: @coleifer where to add migration in this example above?

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to create a record. 
I didn't mention that i was trying to create them in another file, but the procedure is the same as the one coleifer posted on the answer.
The file in which i create the peewee models is `databases.py`, so in the other file i do the following:

```
import databases

databases.db.init('foo.db')

databases.KV.create(name = 'Saul', value= 123)
```

Thanks!